# Como puedo mostrar la informacion de mi pinpad en un input?

Tags: reactjs, modal

Tengo el siguiente codigo para un pin pad,mi objetivo es que se muestren los numeros digitados en mi pinpad en el input al que le di clic para que apareciera (esto lo hago con un Modal enlazado al Input que se encuentra en una card; ya que hago el formulario de un Login):

> Este es mi codigo para el pinpad, como puedo mostrar la informacion de los numeros a los que se les da clic, al dar "aceptar", en el input.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Screen from './Screen';
import Buton from './Button';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
});

class Pinpad extends React.Component {
    //extend component class
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        screen: [],
        sucess: 'SUCESS',
        error: 'ERRO',
        tries: 5, 
        password: ''
      }
    }

    //I tried using an input on the screen component
    //but this worked
    //not sure if "the react way"
    addPassword = val => {
       return this.state.screen.length > 5 ? '' : this.setState({screen: this.state.screen + val});
    }

    /*
    pin = '1234';
    validadePassword = (addPassword, pin) => {
      //return addPassword === pin ? this.state.screen.type === 'password' : this.state.screen.type === 'number';
      console.log(pin);
    }*/

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Pinpad">
          <div className="container" align="center">
            <Screen

              screen={this.state.screen}
              length = {6}>
            </Screen>
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>7</Buton></Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>8</Buton></Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>9</Buton></Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>4</Buton></Button>
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>5</Buton></Button>
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>6</Buton></Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>1</Buton></Button>
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>2</Buton></Button>
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword}>3</Buton></Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Buton handleClick={this.addPassword} class="col align-self-center">0</Buton></Button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <Button variant="outlined" color="primary">Aceptar</Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Pinpad;
```

Este es el codigo de Screen:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Screen = props => (
    <div className="input">
    {props.screen}
    </div>
 );

 export default Screen
```

Este es el codigo del boton:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Buton = ({ children, handleClick})=> (
    <div 
        className={`button-container ${children}`}
        onClick={() => handleClick(children)}>
        {children}
    </div>
);
export default Buton
```

Este es el codigo del Modal

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Pinpad from './inviertete/Pinpad';

function rand() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10;
  }

  function getModalStyle() {
    const top = 50 + rand();
    const left = 50 + rand();

    return {
      top: `${top}%`,
      left: `${left}%`,
      transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
    };
  }

  const styles = theme => ({
    paper: {
      position: 'absolute',
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 50,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
      padding: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
      outline: 'none',
    },
  });

  class SimpleModal extends React.Component {
    state = {
      open: false,
    };

    handleOpen = () => {
      this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;

      return (
        <div>
          {//<Typography gutterBottom>Click to get the full Modal experience!</Typography>
          }
          <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Pin</InputLabel>
          <Input onClick={this.handleOpen} type="password" id="password" autoComplete="current-password" style={{minWidth: 270}} >Open Modal</Input>
          <Modal
            aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
            open={this.state.open}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
          >
            <div style={getModalStyle()} className={classes.paper}>
              <Typography variant="h6" id="modal-title">
                Por favor, digita tu pin:
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle1" id="simple-modal-description">
                El numero maximo de digitos permitidos es de seis:
              </Typography>
              <Pinpad></Pinpad>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  SimpleModal.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  // We need an intermediary variable for handling the recursive nesting.
  const SimpleModalWrapped = withStyles(styles)(SimpleModal);

  export default SimpleModalWrapped;
```

Soy principiante, les agradezco mucho de antemano su colaboracion, estaria encantado de poder seguir aprendiendo de ustedes y de lo genial que es React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolvi mi problema, les comparto el codigo corregido por si a alguien le llega a servir.

Este es mi componente Modal:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Pinpad from './inviertete/Pinpad';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function rand() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10;
  }

  function getModalStyle() {
    const top = 50 + rand();
    const left = 50 + rand();

    return {
      top: `${top}%`,
      left: `${left}%`,
      transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
    };
  }

  const styles = theme => ({
    paper: {
      position: 'fixed',
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 50,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
      padding: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
      outline: 'none',
    },
  });

  class SimpleModal extends React.Component {
    state = {
      open: false,
      password: '',
    };

    handleOpen = () => {
      this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    getPassword = (code) => {
      this.setState({ password: this.state.password+code})
    };

    render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;

      return (
        <div>
          {//<Typography gutterBottom>Click to get the full Modal experience!</Typography>
          }
          <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Pin</InputLabel>
          <Input onClick={this.handleOpen} type="password" id="password" autoComplete="current-password" style={{minWidth: 270}} value={this.state.password}>Open Modal</Input>
          <Modal
            aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
            open={this.state.open}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            align="center"
          >
            <div style={getModalStyle()} className={classes.paper}>
              <Typography variant="h6" id="modal-title" align="center">
                Por favor, digita tu pin:
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle1" id="simple-modal-description">
                El numero maximo de digitos permitidos es de seis:
              </Typography>
              <Pinpad handlePassword={this.getPassword} password={this.state.password}>
              </Pinpad>
              <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => this.handleClose()}>Aceptar</Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  SimpleModal.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  // We need an intermediary variable for handling the recursive nesting.
  const SimpleModalWrapped = withStyles(styles)(SimpleModal);

  export default SimpleModalWrapped;
```

Este es mi componente del Pinpad:

```
import React from 'react';
import Screen from './Screen';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
});

class Pinpad extends React.Component {
    //extend component class
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        screen: [],
        sucess: 'SUCESS',
        error: 'ERRO',
        tries: 5, 
      }
    }

    //I tried using an input on the screen component
    //but this worked
    //not sure if "the react way"
    addPassword = e => {
      console.log(e.target.value)
       return this.state.screen.length > 5 ? '' : this.setState({screen: this.state.screen + e});
    }

    /*
    pin = '1234';
    validadePassword = (addPassword, pin) => {
      //return addPassword === pin ? this.state.screen.type === 'password' : this.state.screen.type === 'number';
      console.log(pin);
    }*/

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Pinpad">
          <div className="container" align="center">
            <Screen

              screen={this.props.password}
              length = {6}>
            </Screen>
            <Typography>
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={7} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>7</Button></Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={8} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>8</Button></Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={9} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>9</Button></Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center"> 
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={4} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>4</Button></Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={5} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>5</Button></Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={6} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>6</Button></Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={1} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>1</Button></Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={2} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>2</Button></Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={3} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>3</Button></Button>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary"><Button value={0} onClick={(e)=>this.props.handlePassword(e.currentTarget.value)}>0</Button></Button>
            </div>
            </Typography>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            </div>
          </div>
      );
    }
  }


  export default Pinpad;
```

Y este es mi componente screen:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Screen = props => (
    <div className="input">
    {props.screen}
    </div>
 );

 export default Screen
```

Con esto a mi ya me corre en mi aplicacion sin ningun problema.